# Как получить данные из PHP в JS symfony 1.4

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

У меня есть в контроллере массив

```
$points = [];

$a['x'] = $point->getPointX();
$a['y'] = $point->getPointY();
$a['content'] = $point->getContent();
$a['title'] = $point->getTitle();

$points = $a;
```

Как я могу этот массив передать в JS?

```
function init() {
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map("contact-map", {
                center: [55.76, 37.64],
                zoom: 10
            });

            var myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
                geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [ points['x'], points['y'] ],
                },
                properties: {
                    balloonContentBody: points['content'],
                    hintContent: points['title'],
                }
            });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
        }
```

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Comment: Если сам текст скрипта формируешь ты - можно его сформировать "вставив" данные прямо в текст. Если такой возможности нет - данные можно получить запросом к серверу. Но тогда функция должна принять данные как параметр или данные должны быть получены в области видимости функции.

Comment: @ksa возможности прямо в лоб, увы, нет

Comment: А добавить параметр в описание функции можешь?

Comment: @ksa добавить могу

Comment: Тогда запросом получай данные. Передавай их функции аргументом. Далее функция их сможет использовать как обычный полученный параметр.